# Is it possible to take the app name again after the app got deleted from iTunes-connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

Since we can have [180 days time for app binary submission](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96489/what-is-the-maximum-time-for-delivering-app-binary-to-app-store), After that window expires the application will be deleted from the itunes-connect.

Then is it possible to create another application with the same name?

ie, is there any possibilities for apple to give the same name to the same user after deletion of the app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, once and App has been deleted, either by you or because of the expiration process, you cannot reuse your SKU or app name in the same account again. It can be used, though, by another developer.

Under the [Deleting an App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH3-SW37) section of the iTunes Connect Developer Guide you'll learn more about the ramifications of an App Deletion.

Comment: Any documentated references?

Comment: @imazik, no need thanx for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apple will not allow to create a new app with the same name that you have created and deleted earlier.

You can refer what [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/1_Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225) is telling about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to re-upload the app under the same name by **choosing a different default language** after deleting it. This might as well be a bug in iTunes Connect though and I wouldn't be surprised if they were to fix it some day.

To be safe, simply update your app with the new version - even an entirely new project.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, the accepted answer is not valid anymore.

Apps can be "Removed" instantly and the name can be taken instantly by another app (even from the same developer account).

See https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev28d17ed35