# Uploading app to app-store with same name for another developer id

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, apple-id, app-store-connect

Let me explain clearly,

I have developed an application and created an app in the app-store with an apple developer id. But, not uploaded the binary version.

Now I need to upload the app with another apple id with the same name. I know if I delete the old one [I can reuse the name with other id](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96495/is-it-possible-to-take-the-app-name-again-after-the-app-got-deleted-from-itunes).

I need to know two things about this,

Is there any time gap required for using the name after deleting the old app(can I create immidietely after deleting the old app)?

Is it possible to use the same Bundle identifier that I used for the old one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the old app's binary version is not uploaded and reviewed, I just renamed that application and then used the name for the new developer id.

Apple accepts the name and the app is now in review.

Comment: I've always wondered this myself. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score -3):

Sorry but this can not be done