# Claiming an app title for your iTunes Connects account

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm setting up my iTunes Connect account and chose an app title etc.  Since I haven't released/published the app to iOS yet, can someone else set up an iTunes Connect app with the same app title and publish it? Or, once you add the app to your iTunes Connect account, do you reserve that title of the app until submission?

Answer (score 1):

If you've created an app record for the app, providing an app name and SKU, then you have registered this name to that iTunes Connect account for 180 days.<sup>[[1]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96489/what-is-the-maximum-time-for-delivering-app-binary-to-app-store)</sup>

After 180 days, the app record is deleted. Once an app record is deleted from iTunes Connect, you can't create an app record with the same app name on that iTunes Connect account.<sup>[[2]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH31-SW37)</sup>